# Unable to use KDE desktop due to autologin

Tags: login, kde, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu but now I want to use a different dekstop (KDE rather than GNOME). I installed KDE Plasma Desktop using the instructions here: https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-on-ubuntu/ and rebooted my laptop but it just auto logs me back into GNOME. I've also tried...

1. removing autologin in my settings:

[Settings > Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksbcC.png)

2. amending /etc/gdm3/custom.conf in terminal/nano

[custom.conf in nano](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ephCU.png)

3. Reinstall KDE full

Neither seems to prevent autologin.

Is there something I'm missing?

My setup:

- Dell XPS 15 9510
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- GNOME version 42.4
- Windowing System X11

Comment: Are you using GDM (Gnome's login manager) or SDDM (KDE's login manager)?

Comment: You mention making changes to `gdm3` to prevent autologin, but are you using `gdm3`?  as adding KDE to an existing install offers to replace the DM with `sddm` - thus any changes to gdm3 configs will do nothing as you opted for that.

Comment: You can always choose to Log Out of GNOME and that will take you to the Login page where you can choose KDE (Kubuntu), and it should login to KDE from then on out even with Auto-Login enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It did not work because you are now using KDE's login manager (SDDM), but you changed settings for GNOME's login manager (GDM).

---

Open System Settings in KDE, and open the settings for Login Screen (SDDM) in the Startup and Shutdown section.

[image]

Click on behavior, and disable automatic login.

[image]

Comment: FYI  to OP.  This should work even if you're not logged into a KDE session; I'm not and used a terminal to open the *KDE System Settings* and could get to the options here.. alas I'm not using *jammy* or 22.04 currently, but I'm convinced it'd work there too.  Alternatively log out, then manually select KDE & login again and you're using KDE.  Good answer :)

Comment: @guiverc What is the terminal command for kde system settings?

Comment: I used `systemsettings`  (I just typed syste<tab><tab> and picked the one I believed it to be & yep. it got me there).   I just tested it on a Lubuntu 22.04 device & it worked on that box too (*though when I looked I'd added `kubuntu-desktop` to that install too; it was a different box to what I used earlier*)